# Button in android increases in height on setting alignparentbottom as true

Tags: android

I am working on a project where there is a registration form and a button at the bottom of the form.The xml for the button is as follows:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnnext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clicked_selector"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

If i set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` , the button increases in height despite setting height as `wrap_content`.If i remove the `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, the button shrinks in size.How do i make it the right size with `wrap_content` for height and width.

EDIT:WHOLE LAYOUT

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frag1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtheading1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="PERSONAL DETAILS-I"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="25dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtfullname"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="FULL NAME"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/lv_dob"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtfullname" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtdob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:editable="false"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="DATE OF BIRTH"
                android:inputType="none"
                android:singleLine="true" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btndob"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtdob"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtdob"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtdob"
                android:background="@drawable/button_clicked_selector"
                android:text="SELECT DATE"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_gender"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lv_dob"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtgendertitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="GENDER:"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGender"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/genderMale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Male"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/genderFemale"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btndob"
                    android:text="Female"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_marital"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_gender"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtmaritaltitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="MARITAL\n STATUS:"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radiomarital"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/marital_single"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Single"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/marital_married"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Married"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtusername1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_marital"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="EMAIL ID"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtpassword1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtusername1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="PASSWORD"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtpassword2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtpassword1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="CONFIRM PASSWORD"
            android:inputType="textPassword" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnnext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_clicked_selector"
        android:text="NEXT"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:BACKGROUND FILE

button_clicked_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient" /> 
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/button_clicked_gradient" /> 
</selector>
```

button_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#00aff0"
      android:endColor="#0081b0"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

button_clicked_gradient.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
    <!--  Gradient Bg for listrow -->
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#00aff0"
      android:endColor="#00aff0"
      android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

EDIT:SCREENSHOT

[image]

Comment: I was unable to replicate this problem

Comment: The problem is caused by layout_alignParentBottom and layout_below together, I can solve this problem if I know your whole layout.

Comment: @Leog Will post the whole layout.

Comment: @Leog if i remove layout_below , the button shrinks in size.

Comment: @AchuthanM So you want the button to be exactly the same size as its background button_clicked_selector?

Comment: After removing the layout_below from the button,does it resolves your issue.

Comment: @A.R. No , it shrunk in size.Is the background causing the issue?

Comment: @Leog , should i post the background xml file here?

Comment: @AchuthanM No you don't, change Button to TextView and have a try.

Comment: @Leog Changing to textview didnt help.It still looks shrunken.

Comment: @AchuthanM So does it shrink size without its button_clicked_selector background?

Comment: @Leog , without the background the button is of right size.

Comment: @AchuthanM So I guess it's the problem of the background. I'm sorry but you have to post the background.

Comment: @Leog will post background file.

Comment: @AchuthanM I copied your layout to my project and remove layout_below  from that button, but did not see the shrinks, it works properly.

Comment: @Leog , I ran on my device and it shrinks.It even shows shrunken in the graphical layout.How do i fix this issue.

Comment: @AchuthanM Could you please post the screen shot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `wrap_content` to the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of your `btnnext1`, and your button background does not have a size too, thus the size of your button is determined by the text in it. As you can see the button is nearly as large as the text in it.

So you can add some padding to the button to make it larger.

Answer (score 2):

Just see you layout, there are two things on Button attributes: `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" and android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"`
Your button's hight will stretch from the bottom of the RelativeLayout to the bottom of the screen, you so can not control it correctly.

Pls remove layout_below, AND set height to fixed size such as 48DP, .... The reason for setting height as fixed size is because you use background for that button (default button background is system background, include size of height already)